# Find description of convex set by equations

Tags: polyhedra, convex-geometry

I have given the polyhedron $P$ which is given by the convex hull of the points $v_1 = (0,0,0), v_2 = (1,0,0), v_3 = (0,1,0), v_4 = (0,1,1)$. I want to find the representation of $P$ as the intersection of closed half-spaces, i.e. I want to find a Matrix $A$ and a vector $b$, such that $P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3: Ax \leq b \}$.

In our lecture notes there is a similar example where a rhombus $Q$ is given by the convex hull of the points $(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$. It was said $Q$ can be described as the set 
\begin{align}
Q = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 ~|~ \exists \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_4 \geq 0, \sum\limits_{i=1}^{4} \lambda_i = 1, x = (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) e_1 + (\lambda_3 - \lambda_4) e_2 \}
\end{align}
with $e_1$ and $e_2$ being the standard unit vectors. Once we find this description we can use Fourier-Motzkin Elimination to find the Matrix $A$. So I was trying to find an analogous description of $P$ given by the vertices I mentioned above, but I failed. My first try was
\begin{align}
P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 ~|~ \exists \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \geq 0, \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} \lambda_i = 1, x = \lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + \lambda_3 (e_2 + e_3)\},
\end{align}
but this set does not contain the point $(0,0,0)$. I had some other attempts but they all did not work out.
So my question is, if there is a certain way to find the correct equations to describe the polyhedron or is it rather a kind of "smart-guessing" ?

Comment: As the dimension of the space/number of variables increases, this problem becomes combinatorially more difficult.  In two dimensions you are essentially determining the cyclic order of the vertices on the boundary of a convex polygon.  In the specific 3D polyhedron you ask about the equations can be found "by inspection" because you have a tetrahedron, so four sides (from the four vertices).  Focus on those, e.g. taking the sides determined by each subset of three vertices and orienting the inequality to be satisfied by the fourth vertex.

Comment: I am not sure, if this is correct what I have done, but what about $P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 ~|~ \exists \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_4 \geq 0, \sum\limits_{i=1}^{4} \lambda_i = 1, x = \lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + \lambda_3 (e_2 + e_3) + \lambda_4 (e_1 - e_1)\}$ ? It feels a bit weird, because of the "$+ 0$" but with the additional $\lambda_4$ I cannot find any point which is not contained in the other set...

Comment: Keep in mind that you are going to need (four) inequalities in the unknowns $x_i$ that are the components of your vector $x$.  What you have written is not of the right form but a valid way to express all the convex combinations.  It just doesn't give you $Ax\le b$ as the problem asks.

Comment: The "additional $\lambda_4$" allows you to express the point $(0,0,0)$ which otherwise you would not be able to write.

Answer (score 1):

In the method that you propose to use, the expression that defines the set is a convex combination of the vertices of the polyhedron. It’s a bit unfortunate that it was presented to you in simplified form since that obscures the simple construction: It’s just a linear combination $\sum_i \lambda_iv_i$ of the vertices with the constraints $\lambda_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i\lambda_i=1$. So, for this tetrahedron, we would have the combination $$\lambda_1(0,0,0)+\lambda_2(1,0,0)+\lambda_3(0,1,0)+\lambda_4(0,1,1) = \lambda_2e_1+(\lambda_3+\lambda_4)e_2+\lambda_4e_3.$$ Even though it doesn’t appear in the final expression, you still need to account for $\lambda_1$ in the constraint $\sum_i\lambda_i=0$. Leaving $\lambda_1$ out of that constraint amounts to fixing it at $0$, in which case all of the points lie on the plane defined by the second through last vertices: the tetrahedron collapses into the triangle $\triangle{v_2v_3v_4}$.

For a small problem like this one, you could take a more direct approach instead. Take the vertices three at a time and find the equation of the corresponding plane, choosing the direction of the normal $n$ so that if the equation of the plane is $n\cdot x=b$ the remaining vertex $v$ satisfies $n\cdot v\le b$. You then stack the coefficients of the resulting equations into the augmented matrix $[A\mid b]$. For example, taking $v_2$, $v_3$ and $v_4$, we can obtain the normal $(1,1,0)$, so an equation of the plane is $x+y=1$. Comparing this to the remaining vertex, we see that the appropriate half-space is $x+y\le1$, so the first row of $A$ is $(1,1,0)$ and the first element of $b$ is $1$. Continuing with the other faces will give you the other three rows.

Answer (score 0):

- $v_1, v_2, v_3$ belong to $x_3=0$
- $v_1, v_2, v_4$ belong to $x_2=x_3$
- $v_1, v_3, v_4$ belong to $x_1=0$
- $v_2, v_3, v_4$ belong to $x_1+x_2=1$

ain't it?

--- rk